# Multiple routing file in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 2.3 has an option to add more routes anytime using RouteSet#add_configuration_file.

Is it possible to do the same in a Rails 3 project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in config/application.rb:

`config.paths.config.routes << File.join(Rails.root, "config/routes/route_file.rb")`

In Rails 3.2 (possibly also Rails 3.1), use:

`config.paths["config/routes"] << Rails.root.join('config/routes/route_file.rb')`

Comment: This isn't working for me in Rails 3.2.1. It isn't defined in the docs either. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application/Configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

To complete Joe Van Dyk's answer, to load all the files the the `config/routes` directory, you must do (in Rails 3.2) :

```
    config.paths["config/routes"] += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'routes', '*.rb').to_s]
```

Answer (score -2):

This method is supported in Rails 3.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Routing/RouteSet/add_configuration_file

Code example is, for example, here:
http://sudomasochism.com/post/62151402/rails-2-3-0-and-routeset-add-configuration-file

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for Rails3. Both the apidock and the example points to Rails 2.3.